# How to only commit files in the unnamed changelist with SVN?

Tags: svn, commit, changelist

I am using the command line SVN client (for speed reasons) and have a changelist of files that I wish to ignore on each commit (much like TortoiseSVN does).  Is there a way to commit all files except a specific changelist or maybe just commit all files not in a changelist?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The changelist is intended for the other way around. Just commit files which are contained in the changelist and not exclude them from committing. If you'd like to ignore certain files, you should put them into the `svn:ignore` property, but only if they are not under version control.

Comment: Problem is they are, I have locally modified them so that they display certain information only to me but don't want everyone else seeing this.

Comment: I wish I could downvote this "feature" of svn. I currently have a boatload of changes in my default changelist and was looking for a way to avoid checking in the couple of files I DON'T want to commit without having to checkin a hundred files by name.

Comment: Looks like Subversion 1.8 is going to have a --changelist "" syntax to target files that do not belong to any changelist. http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#cmdline

Comment: @rlovtang alas, that feature doesn't appear to have made it into 1.8

Answer (score 5):

I use the following one-liner, assuming you have a changelist named TO_IGNORE where you put files you don't want to commit:

```
svn st | sed -e "/^--- Changelist 'TO_IGNORE'/,/^--- Changelist/d" | grep '^[ADMR]' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn ci
```

this relies on the fact that "svn st" first lists all files not in any changelist, then all changelists one after the other.

The sed commands deletes all lines between the changelist you want to ignore until the next one.

The grep is used to limit Added, Deleted, Modified, and Replaced files to the commit.

The awk extracts the file name from the svn st output.

Comment: This doesn't quite work with binary files - the awk command prints out the + symbol rather than the file name.  I changed it to awk '{print $NF}' which seems to work well.